# Is there a way to correct the TalkBack pronunciation for the app_name or activity label?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I've this problem: I have developed an app for Italian users. My app has an English name and the TalkBack pronunciates it in a wrong way! For example, the TalkBack says the word "What" in this way: "W - H - At".

So, is there a way to correct the TalkBack pronunciation for the name of my app or activity label? Maybe via a contentDescription or something like this...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is not currently a way to override TTS pronunciation.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong! You might try taking a look at the [`TtsSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TtsSpan.html) class.

Comment: Mmm this looks interesting! Thank you, I will try!